# How to pass an array from Java to Ajax

Tags: java, html, ajax

I am new to Ajax and would have thought there would be plenty of examples of passing an array from java to ajax; however, I have not been able to find them. I want to pass three strings to ajax and then display them in HTML. My java code is:

```
System.out.println("Authenticated");
String json = new Gson().toJson(questionList);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

The ajax is:

```
dataType: "json";
alert(responseJson);
var result = $.parseJSON(responseJson); <-- this line fails
$('#question1').val(result.question1);
$('#question2').val(result.question2);
$('#question3').val(result.question3);
```

The alert displays "Question 1 is a?,Question 2 is b?,Question 3 is c?".

How do I pass each of the strings to display in the HTML. I suspect I need to build the array in java differently as well as receive the result in ajax differently; however, I can not find an applicable example. I do not want to use unstring as the question could contain "," or other delimiter used.

Comment: What  `json` do you get after `String json = new Gson().toJson(questionList);`? Because from the alert displays, it seems   not a valid json string.

Comment: I added "System.out.println("json = " + json);  and the result is: "json = ["Question 1 is a?","Question 2 is b?","Question 3 is c?"]".

Comment: for me , you are re parsing the string which is already in json. you set application/json , so i don't see the need of parse in ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `responseJosn` you get from ajax is already been parsed. No need to parse it again. It's an `Array`. So the JS code would be like:

```
dataType: "json";           //this line should not be here
alert(responseJson);
//var result = $.parseJSON(responseJson); <-- this line fails
$('#question1').val(responseJson[0]);
$('#question2').val(responseJson[1]);
$('#question3').val(responseJson[2]);
```